# Add Jquery ui button dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a javascript function that removes the existing buttons and adds new ones instead.

Here is the code:

```
 function FunctionName(){
     ("button").remove();
     // This works fine.
     //but however, with the following add code, I don;t get a jquery ui button.
     var element  = document.createElement("input");
     element.setAttribute("type","button");
     // other code
     divName = get <div> by ID;
     divName.appendChiled(element);
 }
```

Is there any way to add a jquery ui button dynamically:

like:

`divName.add("button");`

It did not work...

Comment: @a-dilla: THe button does not appear with that statement. Atleast a blank button or a sign of it must appear...

Comment: @a-dilla: The same problem.. get a normal button

Answer (score 19):

To add a jQuery UI button using jQuery:

```
$('#selector') // Replace this selector with one suitable for you  
  .append('<input type="button" value="My button">') // Create the element  
  .button() // Ask jQuery UI to buttonize it  
  .click(function(){ alert('I was clicked!');}); // Add a click handler
```

Comment: With jQuery at "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" .button() should not be used. Removing it, it worked.

Comment: Hmm, .button() comes from jQuery UI, not jQuery core, so not sure what is responsible for the difference you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you can buttonize any input with jQuery-UI by calling `button()`

```
var element = document.createElement("input").button();
```

Comment: maybe instead of the remove() you should call replaceWith("whatever-you-what-your-button-to-be").button()

Comment: this get me a: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLButtonElement> has no method 'button'

Answer (score 2):

I just created a button dynamically with the following code. The key part is the .button() part, and it seems to work good for me.

```
var self = this;
var exitButton = $(document.createElement("a"));
exitButton.attr({
    'href': '#',
    'id': 'exitSlideshowButton',
});
exitButton.click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    self.exitSlideshow();
});
exitButton.text("Exit Slideshow Mode")
exitButton.button();
exitButton.appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me

`$('#selector').append('<input type="button" value="My button">');`

`$('#selector').click(function(){ alert('I was clicked!');});`

Comment: I like this answer because it only uses jQuery and not jQuery UI

Answer (score 1):

I think @Stony was close, except the `.button()` and `.click()` methods were being added to the original selector element, not the actual button. You should create an id for the button then select that button and call `button().click()` on that.

This is probably causing some kind of exception with the call to `button()` as commented under that post.

Answer (score 0):

[Ninja UI](http://ninjaui.com) works this way by default, without hacking in HTML that gets overridden.

You can create the button as a variable before the DOM is even ready.

```
var $button = $.ninja.button({
  html: 'Post Your Answer'
}).select(function () {
  // Your action here.
});
```

When the DOM is ready, append wherever you'd like the button to go.

```
$('body').append($button);
```

Answer (score 0):

I applied from @Stony and it worked for me.

```
function addMyButton(btID){
    var temp = "<button id='" + btID + "'>My Button</button>";
    $( "#selector" ).html(temp);
    $( "#" + btID )
        .button()
        .click(function(){
            alert( "I was clicked!");
        });
}
```