# How to get button ID, assign to a var for use in a dialog form

Tags: jquery

I have a page with multiple dynamically created buttons. I need to be able to grab the button id, on click, and assign it to a variable for use in the dialog-form. I've tried several different ways to do this including attempting to grab the value as per below. None of these work and this way simply stops the dialog box from submitting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$( ".create-user" )
.button()
.click(function() {
var photoID=this.id;
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );

});

<button class="create-user" id="1">Create new user</button>
<button class="create-user" id="2">Create new user</button>
<button class="create-user" id="3">Create new user</button>
```

Comment: what does `$( ".create-user" ).button()`  mean?

Comment: And where exactly are you using `photoID` ?

Comment: If the buttons are dynamically created you are going to have to run that code after you create the buttons http://stackoverflow.com/q/4351813/1161353

Comment: The buttons are created on page load. Clicking the button opens up a modal dialog box using #dialog-form.

The photoID var will be sent as one of the form variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the other answers only address the opening of the dialog and not how to use the id variable of the button in the dialog itself. Try this:
Simply set a global variable for your dialog to use. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95B2G/1/

```
var myid;

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#here').html(myid);
    }
});

$( ".create-user" )
    .button()
    .click(function() {
    myid = $(this).attr('id');
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.[button](http://jqueryui.com/button/) function that you are using is not for this purpose so remove it and Simply try this

```
$(".create-user" ).click(function() {
alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$(".create-user").click(function() {
    var photoID = this.id;
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons are created after the page and your javascript is laoded, then you need to use the `.live()` function:

```
$( ".create-user" ).live('click', function() {
    var photoID= $(this).attr('id');
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```